# How to auto width table by content?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This is my site layout http://www.incredibleanime.com/series/area-no-kishi/
As you can see the cell with the picture in it has a big gap between the next cell. How can I make it auto with by it's content? I can't give it a fixed width cause the picture will always have different width size.

Comment: since you have only one row in your table, cell width is auto by default

Comment: I have 2 rows. If the cell is auto why does the cell with the picture have a gap between the two cells?

Comment: I would suggest to have div structure instead of table. If you can't change it. you can give fixed width for the first td (E.g: width: 100px). Table resize itself even if you give fixed width.

Comment: that is because the div "Series cover" has a great width than the image it contains so your cells adjusts itself to the div (which is also its content) rather than the image

Comment: @sinaspd so how would I give the div #series-cover an auto width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-table;` in your td. it will solve your problem.

```
td {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Just apply this css and check.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to set width: 100% and height auto for image and need set bigger width for text part http://prntscr.com/6bnv05